# How do I run test cases for a class written in Java, using Robot framework?

Tags: java, eclipse, robotframework

I am trying to learn how to use Robot Framework. I created simple Java project, using Eclipse. It contains one package - `test` and in this package there is only one class - `MyKeywords`. Here is the class content:

```
package test;

public class MyKeywords {

    public String sayHi(String name)
    {
            return "Hello " +name ;
    }

    public String sayHi()
    {
            return "Hello World!";
    }

    public String typeOf(Object param)
    {
            return param.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}
```

Then I created simple .txt file, whic is supposed to contain the test cases. Here is the my_suite.txt file:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           test.MyKeywords

*** Test Cases ***
MyTestCase
    ${message}    say hi
    Log    ${message}

MyTestCase2
    ${message}    say hi    my_name
    Log    ${message}

MyTestCase3
    ${message}    type of    42
    Log    ${message}
```

Whenever, I try to paste the my_suite.txt file into the project directory, it goes under the bin directory.
After that, when I run `pybot my_suite.txt` from the terminal (I am on Mac OS), I got the following message:

> [ ERROR ] Error in file
>   '/Users/b18/Documents/workspace/Example/my_suite.txt': Importing
>   test library 'test.MyKeywords' failed: Module 'test' does not contain
>   'MyKeywords'.
>   ============================================================================== My Suite
>
> ============================================================================== MyTestCase
>   | FAIL | No keyword with name 'say hi' found.
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ MyTestCase2
>   | FAIL | No keyword with name 'say hi' found.
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ MyTestCase3
>   | FAIL | No keyword with name 'type of' found.
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ My Suite
>   | FAIL | 3 critical tests, 0 passed, 3 failed 3 tests total, 0 passed,
>   3 failed
>   ============================================================================== Output:  /Users/b18/Documents/workspace/Example/output.xml Log:
>   /Users/b18/Documents/workspace/Example/log.html Report: 
>   /Users/b18/Documents/workspace/Example/report.html

Where is my mistake and what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing languages here.

You are using Java keywords, with pybot (which is pure python - and doesn't support java).

You need to use jybot instead (you can download the jar and run it with java)

Jybot is based on Jython - and supports python and java code.